# Problem reading and writing files on devices that mount sd cards

Tags: android, path

I have a problem writing and reading files in devices where sd cards are present, I use this code to get the write and read path and everything works well in devices without sd cards.

Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath

any advice on methods to solve the problem?

Comment: Please give some more details. Also add the android tag at least.

Comment: I have problems running the application on devices that mount sd cards, the problem happens when I have to write or read files in memory which does not happen when there is no external memory on the device.

Comment: I had meant to edit (i.e. you should) your question (instead of adding a comment).